# Multiple Update query Locks MYSQL Table

Tags: mysql, database

My Requirement is to update user block mail list based upon email addresses given by client. Email addresses may be in form of MD5, sha1 or simple email addresses.
Currently when i update user email address with list of emails then after taking so much time it locks table and no further query process on that table. I have also put indexes on both tables.

**Query:**

```
UPDATE database1.nl_user u 
INNER JOIN database2.email_blacklist e 
SET u.block_mail_list = IF(u.block_mail_list is NULL OR u.block_mail_list='',e.listId,concat(u.block_mail_list,',',e.listId)),e.isMatch = 1 
WHERE (md5(u.email) = e.email OR u.email = e.email OR sha1(u.email) = e.email);
```

**User table counts:** "168219"
**Blocked email lists counts:** "36,000"

Thanks for your time, and looking forward to hear from you guys.

Thanks!
Regards,

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear to me what happens. Does your query take too much time and you want it to be faster so you can run your next update earlier? Does (one) update takes "forever"/does not finish? Can't your read from the table while you update it (but want to)? Are you trying to run multiple updates on the table and they run into a deadlock or a timeout? Are you trying to run multiple updates on the table and they slow each other down or one has to wait for the first one to finish (but they actually finish)?

Comment: Hi, its single update. Query keeps on working and taking too much time to process, what i observe this query may take more than 4 hours to complete and sometimes not complete. thanks for your time. (or in short its in cron script that runs once a day)

Comment: Well, you would need to add the explain plan (the output of `explain update database1.nl...`) to your question so we can check if your indexes are ok, but I would assume that executing 170k sha and md5s on every execution may just take 4 hours. You should probably store them precalculated (and indexed) in your usertable (as a generated column or using a trigger to keep them up-to-date), which should make your query run in seconds.

Comment: thanks, i'll check and let you know. Appreciated your response.